# How to get the microphone streaming input file when using blocks?

Tags: gradio

I'm trying to convert a simple example from interface to block, and I have missing part

The app displays every 2 seconds the temporary recording wav file name:

```
import gradio as gr
import time

def transcribe(audio, state=""):
    time.sleep(2)
    return audio


inf = gr.Interface(
    fn=transcribe,
    inputs=[
        gr.Audio(source="microphone", type="filepath", streaming=True),
    ],
    outputs=[
        "textbox",
    ],
    live=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    inf.launch()
```

I'm trying to write this simple example with blocks, but I don't know how to connect the transcribe function to the new file event ?

```
import gradio as gr
import time

def transcribe(audio, state=""):
    time.sleep(2)
    return audio

with gr.Blocks() as demo:
    input_mic = gr.Audio(source="microphone", type="filepath", streaming=True)
    out_text  = gr.Textbox()

# how to connect transcribe function to the input_mic event ?

if __name__ == "__main__":
    demo.launch()
```